# Angular 5 DataTables Plugin - How to pass data from HTML in TypeScript function call

Tags: typescript, angular5

I have the component.html code below, from a DataTables plugin, working. When you select rows, and click the Delete button, the `handleDelete()` function is called. I do not know how to pass the selected rows to `handleDelete()`. I found a [DataTables Editor example](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/api/softDelete) using jQuery that defines what I'd like to send, but I prefer to use only a5 code. I've tried naming the table, and using an [(ngModel)] parameter, but that causes compile errors.

```
jQuery parameter
var rows = table.rows( {selected: true} ).indexes();

component.html
<sa-datatable
  [options]="{
    data: sysMsgs,
    columns: [
      {data: 'checked'},
      {data: 'rowid'},
      {data: 'senderID'},
      {data: 'message'},
      {data: 'dateCreated'}
    ],
    buttons: [ 'copy', 'csv', 'pdf', 'print',
      {
        extend: 'selected',
        text: 'Delete',
        action: handleDelete()
      }
    ],
    columnDefs: [
      {
        targets: 0,
        orderable: false,
        className: 'select-checkbox'
      },
      {
        targets: [2],
        visible: true
      }
    ],
    select: {
      style: 'os',
      selector: 'td:first-child'
    },
    order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]],
    searching: true,
    search: {
      smart: false                  
    }               
  }"
  tableClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th data-hide="mobile-p">Select</th>
        <th data-hide="mobile-p">ID</th>
        <th data-hide="mobile-p">Sender</th> 
        <th data-hide="mobile-p">Message</th>
        <th data-hide="mobile-p">Date Sent</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
</sa-datatable>
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved with the help of the DataTables community. You can see the solution [here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/144188).